# How to get in postgresql using regex the substring on the left or right to the nth delimiter

Tags: regex, postgresql

Let's say I have a variable string like:

```
"Hello. Now is the time. Before. After "
```

What regular expression could I use with regexp_replace (Postgres) in order to get the substring on the left/right of the second or nth delimiter character, suppose a "." as delimiter:

If I want the left side string on the second "." I should get:

```
"Now is the time"
```

If I want the right side string on the second "." I should get:

```
"Before"
```

This is on Postgresql 8.1 (I know...)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using string_to_array():

To get the left side string from the second ".":

```
SELECT (STRING_TO_ARRAY('Hello. Now is the time. Before. After ', '.'))[2];
 string_to_array  
------------------
  Now is the time
```

To get the right side string from the second ".":

```
SELECT (STRING_TO_ARRAY('Hello. Now is the time. Before. After ', '.'))[3];
 string_to_array 
-----------------
  Before
```

Though I would like to know how to do it with regexp_replace() since I suspect it could be faster.

Answer (score 0):

`split` looks much more appropriate for this scenario, especially if your *n* isn't constant.

But I can't resist a regex puzzle.

You could use `substring` with a regex to return the n'th lazy (shortest) group of characters terminated with a . or end-of-line.

Postgres' substring capturing picks up the last value of the first capture group, so you explicitly say (?:) not to capture the outer group and the delimiter.

so that gives

```
  SELECT substring('Hello. Now is the time. Before. After ', '(?:(.*?)(?:$|\.)){2}');
```

(and {3} for the third group, i.e. *after* the second delimiter)

You may want to trim off whitespace given your sample.

note - if you're writing a csv parser in regex, **don't!**